# How to get source code from native dll?

Tags: dll, native, reflector

How can i get source code from native dll ? With Reflector no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot.

Strictly speaking, you also cannot get the source code of a *managed* dll with Reflector (e.g. there are no comments; and if it's been obfucated you also will not see the source code). The .NET Reflector is just **very** good at disassembling the MSIL code.

You *can* **disassemble** a native dll, you just won't like it. For example, i am trying to debug a crash in code that isn't mine:

```
CPU Disasm
Address   Hex dump          Command                                  Comments
20C46D9B  |>  8B4424 14     |MOV EAX,DWORD PTR SS:[LOCAL.1]
20C46D9F  |.  8B40 10       |MOV EAX,DWORD PTR DS:[EAX+10]
20C46DA2  |.  83C0 08       |ADD EAX,8
20C46DA5  |>  8B08          |/MOV ECX,DWORD PTR DS:[EAX]
20C46DA7  |.  3B0F          ||CMP ECX,DWORD PTR DS:[EDI]             ; Crash with EDI=00000008
20C46DA9  |.  75 12         ||JNE SHORT 20C46DBD
20C46DAB  |.  83EE 04       ||SUB ESI,4
20C46DAE  |.  83C7 04       ||ADD EDI,4
20C46DB1  |.  83C0 04       ||ADD EAX,4
20C46DB4  |.  83FE 04       ||CMP ESI,4
20C46DB7  |.^ 73 EC         |\JAE SHORT 20C46DA5
```

But source code? No.